# DKIM aligned but not authenticated for mailboxes moved to Exchange Online in a hybrid configuration

Tags: dkim, exchange-hybrid

For mailboxes migrated to our tenant, they have this in the received message header of external recipients after migration:

arc=fail (body hash mismatch);

SPF/DKIM/DMARC all pass using the records published in our own DNS. We are in a hybrid config with only a handful of mailboxes in EXO currently. Issue goes away if you move it back to on prem. Inbound/outbound email goes thru on prem still using a centralized mail transport for the EXO config.

I even added "Microsoft.com" as a trusted ARC sealer but the issue persists.

Comment: Better open a support ticket to confirm if the issue is with EXO servers.
A thread which may be related: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/deployment-networking/microsoft-s-e-mailservers-break-dkim-on-non-ascii-characters/m-p/1774384

Comment: I looked at that but doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your configuration and make sure you make special rule in your tenant for outgooing email to be routed at the correct door step.

In a hybrid setup the tenant <-> onprem connection is used to sync mailbox only, not for the email routing. It mean if you did nothing more than that connector, then your exchange online email outgooing mailflow is gooing thru Microsoft directly.

Comment: We have configured 'centralized mail transport' when running the HCW so mail does get routed back to our on premise servers and this is confirmed in the message headers.

Comment: @Srfndoc If your mailflow is working as intended; in your on-prem setup what service do the DKIM/DMARC signature ? as it's not built-in. If an external service please check the log to make sure it dont fail a security check. (I state it as those email would be seen as relayed)

Comment: That has been looked at and nothing found.  As mentioned before, if I move the mailbox back to on premise the issue goes away so its definitely something in Microsoft's mail routing that is causing the body hash issue.   Thanks

Comment: @Srfndoc If the service that sign the email see those email, but refuse to sign it because of a header or something changed, it's the service you must correct. A workaround if it's an external service that sign is to allow EXO to send via that provider directly maybe

Comment: EXO is not signing for any of our messages (DKIM signing is disabled for our tenant address) but our on prem infrastructure is correctly signing our outbound email with our DKIM cert and that passes all tests (including SPF/DMARC).  Its just the 'arc=fail (body hash mismatch);" seen in the message header that is the issue.

Comment: @Srfndoc I know, I try to simply understand your mailflow, as we dont have much information. Exchange on-prem can't out of the box sign DMARC/DKIM, thus why I try to understand how it's signed in your case, and where it can block.

Comment: We're using 'centralized mail transport' in a hybrid configuration with a 3rd party ESG that signs all outbound messages with our DKIM cert.  This works great for on premise mailboxes but mailboxes moved to EXO are getting the additional message header I already mentioned ('arc=fail (body hash mismatch)) when sending to external recipients.

Comment: @Srfndoc Thanks for the "3rd party ESG" info, first time you mention it. No need to repeat the question. The log from ESG told what ?

Comment: Nothing in the ESG logs.  Stamps our DKIM cert with no issues and sends the message.